# Using Formik setFieldValue on componentDidUpdate or on handleSubmit (error: not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm trying to use the formik action `setFieldValue`. I've got a form inside a form (its a form and then a dialog opens with a different forms, but some fields depend on what was written in the first form).

The data sending is fine, i just send it as props....however..I'm trying to use `setFieldValues` to set some hidden fields from that form (hidden as in no-input), but i can't seem to make it work.

I've tried using it in `componentDidUpdate` as `this.props.setFieldValue` and i also tried passing `setFieldValue` to my submit function like so

```
onSubmit={(values, setFieldValue) => this.handleSubmit(values, setFieldValue)}
```

Nothing seems to be working. `setFieldValue` is always throwing `not a function`

Answer (score 0):

try `this.props.form.setFieldValue`

Answer (score 0):

check the brackets around the function:

```js
onSubmit={(values, {setFieldValue}) => [...]
```

be sure to have similar synthax on parameter declaration after the formic tag:

```html
<Formik  ... >
    {({isSubmitting, setFieldValue}) => (
        <Form> ...
```